# How to use Alert Dialogue inside uiThread?

Tags: android, multithreading

Following is code snipper of **ConnectActivity** that extends AppCompatActivity that tries to create AlertDialogue

```
new AsyncTask < Void, Void, Boolean > () {
  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground(Void...params) {
   try {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {

      while (true) {
       Socket socket = null;
       try {
        socket = new Socket("192.168.0.32", 11311);
        Log.i("CON", "Connected!");
        socket.close();
       } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("CON", "Disconnected!");

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
          AlertDialog alertDialog;
          alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();
          alertDialog.setTitle("Network error");
          alertDialog.setMessage("Check network connection and try again.");
          alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            finish();
           }
          });
          alertDialog.show();
         }
        });

        break;

       }
       try {
        wait(5000);
       } catch (Exception e) {

       }

      }

     }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
    return true;
   } catch (Exception e) {

    return false;
   }
  }
```

The line `AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext()).create();` gives error:

**java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.**

so I tried replacing this line with `AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();` but `this` here represents Runnable and not context. How should I correct this code?

**Styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/PrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/PrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="edu.academy.cs573.netg">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        tools:replace="android:icon"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launch"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
        <activity android:name=".LicenseInfoActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".ConnectActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="standard"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>

        <service android:name=".NodeMainExecutorService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".NodeMainExecutorService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: provide content of style.xml file

Comment: using asynctask i suggest all the UI changes must be in onPostexecute method..

Comment: did you extend your activity with ActionBarActivity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass activity context here like this

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this).create();
```

if you want to pass the application context then use app comapact theme for your application. which is definately defined in styles.xml file

but you need to show the dialog in `onProgressUpdate()` method. you dont need to run ui thread. when async task already have a method to show some output on ui.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I will try your suggestion of doing this thing in onProgressUpdate().

Answer (score 0):

It's good to call create `AlertDialog` before calling the `AsyncTask`.
You can check the net connectivity before making call to fetch something.

```
alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourAcitvity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert).create();
```

Additionally you can provide the theme to alert dialog `(android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert).`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in application tag

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

in your Manifest